# NodeJS assigning local variable from open-exchange-rate callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, callback, scope

Consider the following method that I execute from an REST API GET request. I am consuming the open-exchange-rates module as described in their [documentation](https://openexchangerates.org/documentation#example-nodejs-npm).

```
//This function will validate the received
//params and invoke the third
//party api call
function findLatestRate(params) {
//Break point
 debugger;
 // Result Variable
 var jsonObj = {};     

 // Get latest exchange rates from API and pass to callback function
oxr.latest(function(err) { //node callback structure
    if(err) {
        //Print stack trace according to enviroment
        console.log(
             config.node_env === 'development' ? 
             err.toString() : 
             'Error occurred when trying to consume oxr API'
            );

        return false;
    }
    // Apply exchange rates and base rate to 'fx' library object:
    fx.rates = oxr.rates; //Rates Currency from APU call
    fx.base = oxr.base; //Base Currency from API call
    //Prepare jsonObj according to params[IF IMPLEMENTING THE FOLLOWING CODE OUTSIDE THE CALLBACK, GET AN 500 ERROR FOR THE VERY FIRST TIME]
    if(params.toCurrency && params.toCurrency in config.currencies_list) {
        //prepare result for base currency to specified currency
        jsonObj.baseCurrency = {
            'fromCurrency': config.baseCurrency,
            'amount': params.amount
        }; 
        jsonObj.toCurrency = {
            'toCurrency':  params.toCurrency,
            'amountRate': fx(params.amount).from(config.baseCurrency).to(params.toCurrency)
        };
    } else {
        jsonObj.statusCode = 400;
        jsonObj.error = 'Bad request';
        jsonObj.message = 'Only the following exchange currencies are available: ' +
                          Object.keys(config.currencies_list);
    }
    console.log('jsonObj within callback looks great: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
 });
console.log('jsonObj outside callback still empty: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
return JSON.stringify(jsonObj); }
```

The problem is that I aiming to return the jsonObj object from this function intending to assign their respective values within the oxr.latest callback.

However outside of this method still empty. How can I ensure that jsonObj is properly assigned in other to return it from findLatestRate(params) function?

Comment: From what I see you want to return jsonObj, but its value  is assigned inside async callback. My recommendation is to use promise.

Comment: Yep. Actually I eventually implemented promises with Q and problem solved !!!